# Refactor Express Router in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Howe to i prevent using this middleware repeatedly on each endpoint. is there a way i can use the isUserAuth and isAdminAuth just once and it will apply on the other routes without repeating it on each route/endpoints?

```
const { createBranch, getAllBranch, getBranch } = require('../controllers/user')
const { isUserAuth, isAdminAuth } = require('../middlewares/auth')

const router = require('express').Router()

// branch
router.post('/', isUserAuth, isAdminAuth, createBranch)
router.get('/', isUserAuth, isAdminAuth, getAllBranch)
router.get('/:id', isUserAuth, isAdminAuth, getBranch)
router.put('/:id', isUserAuth, isAdminAuth, getBranch)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Have you tried `router.use(isUserAuth)`?

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `router.use(isUserAuth);`. You can find the documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)